# How to highlight the class from an object prop in vue.js with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need help or suggestion in highlighting / toggling a class and displaying data I'm just using blade/server-side in passing props, so from this in blade

````
<chat-app :respondent="{{ $user[0]->respondent }}" :user="{{ auth()->user() }}"></chat-app>```
````

then inside the ChatApp.vue file

```
<message-inbox :contact="respondent" :messages="messages"></message-inbox>
```

the `contact` prop there contains the user object that we'll send the chat to... including his id and display name and other basic details..

now I want to fetch all the messages but also highlighting that specific respondent's message.

```html
<li class="bg-blue flex flex-no-wrap items-center text-black cursor-pointer p-3">
                <img class="flex justify-center items-center flex-no-shrink w-12 h-12 bg-grey rounded-full font-semibold text-xl text-white mr-3" :src="userAvatar" alt="">
                <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
                    <div class="flex justify-between mb-1">
                        <h2 class="font-semibold text-sm">
                            <i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i> {{  conversation.respondent }}
                        </h2>
                        <span class="text-sm">
                            <i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i>
                            10:00
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-sm truncate">
                        <span>
                            Some latest messages from this conversation.
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

```
props : {
        contact : {
            type : Object, 
            default : null
        },
        messages : { 
            type : Array,   
            default : []
        },
    }
```

Comment: do u know the specific repondent to be heighlighted?

Comment: Yeah the one's in the contact `prop`  there but I think I have to loop all the messages that has been made by the current logged on user..

Comment: What should I do here sir, should I just loop all through the messages that are made by the user ?

Comment: I think you loop through all the message and then check if that sends the message that u have it in props is equal to  one of ur message you should highlighted the message with vue class binding.

Comment: `axios.get(this.fetch_messages_endpoint, {
    params :  {
     user_id : api.user.id, 
     respondent_id : this.contact.id
    }
   }).then(response => {
    this.conversations = response.data;
    // console.log(response.data);
   }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
   });
` this one's not calling inside `mounted(){
  this.fetch_messages(); 
 }`

Comment: can u show me the messages array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203169/discussion-between-dawlatzai-ghousi-and-thebast).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following to highlight the mentioned respondent.

1. Change your `li` tag as below code:

`<li class="bg-blue flex flex-no-wrap items-center text-black cursor-pointer p-3" :class="{'highlight': conversation.respondent == respondent}">
   <img class="flex justify-center items-center flex-no-shrink w-12 h-12 bg-grey rounded-full font-semibold text-xl text-white mr-3" :src="userAvatar" alt="">
      <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
           <div class="flex justify-between mb-1">
                <h2 class="font-semibold text-sm">
                 <i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i> {{  conversation.respondent }}
                </h2>
                <span class="text-sm">
                  <i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i>
                            10:00
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="text-sm truncate">
              <span>
                   Some latest messages from this conversation.
              </span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </li>`

2. Add highlight `class` in your `CSS` part as below:

   `.highlight {
     color: yellow;
   }`